# Updating multiple array object values with useState in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

Feels like I'm frustratingly close to solving this, but not sure how to update all of the values in a given object array with useState. Here's an example:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([
       {key: 1,
        value: 25},
       {key: 2,
        value: 30}
        ])
```

And then assume on a button click I want to add 10 to the value of every item in the array:

```
    const handleClick = () => {

    const newData = data.map(item => item.value + 10)

     setData ([
         ...data, ???

     ])
```

newData delivers an updated array, but I'm not sure how to use the Hook to update the state. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `functional state updater` and return the mapped result. Also note that since each value is an object you must clone and update just the **value field**

```
 const handleClick = () => {
     setData (prevData => data.map(item => ({...item, value: item.value+10})));
}
```

To put it in your way, it would be like

```
const handleClick = () => {

    const newData = data.map(item => { 
          return {...item, value: item.value + 10}
    });

     setData(newData);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You should setData to the result of your map iteration. It should be something like this:

```
const handleClick = () => {

   const newData = data.map(item => item.value + 10)

   setData(newData)
}
```