# Editing multiple object value in an object array with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object array similar to below

```
[array1, setArray1] = useState(
        [
        {
          name: "somename",
          count: 0,
          division: "somedivision",
          cost: 1000,
        },
        {
          name: "secondname",
          count: 0,
          division: "somedivision",
          cost: 2000,
        },
      ]
)
```

How can i individually update the cost value of each object in my list?

I was thinking of something like
setArray1((previous) => ({...previous, cost: newcost}))

But how can i do this for multiple objects in an object array?

Comment: 1. create a copy of sufficiently deep level 2. update it 3. call setArray1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating multiple array object values with useState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804153/updating-multiple-array-object-values-with-usestate-in-react)

Comment: @ChrisG The example link you provided shows a situation where they want to update the  entire list value by 10 and i can understand the logic there. In my case, i need to update the data individually with different values based on values i get from another api call response.

Comment: @CodinRockz Then update the data individually in the callback.

Comment: Feel free to look for a better fit: [list](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+update+multiple+objects+in+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: @xehpuk - I have another list which has cost. lets say [cost1, cost2...]. How can i update the current list (cost) element only with the cost from corresponding cost array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const App = () =>{
  const [array, setArray] = React.useState([
        {
          name: "somename",
          count: 0,
          division: "somedivision",
          cost: 1000,
        },
        {
          name: "secondname",
          count: 0,
          division: "somedivision",
          cost: 2000,
        },
  ])
  const updateCosts = () => {
    let newCosts = [1002, 2006]
    setArray(previous => 
      previous.map((elem, index)=> {
        return({...elem, cost: newCosts[index]})
      })
     )
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <button onClick={()=>updateCosts()}>Update costs</button>
    { array.map(elem => <p key={elem.name}>{`Product ${elem.name} Cost ${elem.cost}`}</p>) }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: can i use this without useEffects ?

Comment: @CodinRockz Why?

Comment: Why not ? @CodinRockz answer edited

Comment: cheers mate, can you also please add the previous code with useEffects, so i could compare. I will check and provide update soon. @JeanJacquesGourdin

Comment: The code is exactly the same, I mean just the display changed, the important part is in updateCost function .useEffect were used to apply a modification on render to avoid user interaction, I just put sequins on the code by asking user when to update. You can still have the previous version by checking the edits on the post

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin - The code works to update the cost table, but the changes are not rendering in the front end table. The front end still has old data. I am trying to learn how to update

Comment: @CodinRockz I answered your question please ask a new one if you don't know how to fetch data or check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097949/how-to-print-async-data-in-react/73098004#73098004

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin - Thank you very much for your detailed code snippet and help answering. Appreciate it. I can confirm the code you provided works well. I will do some more checks with my other problems and if needed i will create a new thread asking for help. cheers.